# Free homepage carousel

Tags: layout, frontend

Can anyone recommend a free extension that allows a carousel to be placed on the hompage with rotating images?

The images should be able to be uploaded in the admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Qbanner by Qaz](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/qaz-q-banner-slider-image-6799.html). It works very well and is easy to customize.

A big plus is the admin section that offers a lot of options for placing the banner without the need to edit layout files and it offers a nice grid for the uploaded slides.

We did replace the frontend javascript with [jQuery Cycle slider](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) to make it responsive.
This is also easy to do by copying `app/design/frontend/default/default/qaz/qbanner/qbanner.content.top.phtml` to your local template folder and replacing it with the code found on the cycle slider website using the Qbanner functions to build the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[There are several available at Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=1&pl=0&te=0&q=carousel&pr=0:0&t=0&p=1). I did a search for the word "carousel" and chose "free".

Comment: I was looking for a recommendation.  There are so many available